# lxc container : password and username

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, container

I am trying to run wine in a 64b OS ( LUNA ) so i did follow this  [guide](http://wiki.winehq.org/WineOn64bit/) ! to set up wine , and i did chose to follow the first option : **lxc container**

Problem arise when i have to run the container:

> sudo lxc-start -n my32bitbox

I am asked for a user-name and a password that i do not  know.

I did try : root/root; user:user; my-username at the OS:my-password at the OS; ubuntu:ubuntu etc etc etc .

But not luck so far. if someone out there can help me put here, I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Attention**: this answer **was** correct at the time (2013), now it is not any longer: the correct way to do it is the one in *Nanne*'s answer.

---

From the reference you gave, it seems you are trying to set up an LXC in `Ubuntu`. If this is so, [this easy-to-locate Web page](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lxc.html) tells you that default username/password pair in newly-minted LXC's are:

```
  username: ubuntu
  password: ubuntu
```

Comment: This is no longer the case. You need to attach to the root user, then use `passwd` to set the root password.

Answer (score 16):

On newer installs, at least on my current install, you get this message instead of the old ubuntu/ubuntu message: (emph. mine)

> You just created an Ubuntu container (release=trusty, arch=amd64, variant=default)
>
> To enable sshd, run: apt-get install openssh-server
>
> **For security reason, container images ship without user accounts
>   and without a root password.**
>
> Use lxc-attach or chroot directly into the rootfs to set a root password
>   or create user accounts.

so how do you create a new user on a new LXC?

As hinted, you can either chroot into the rootfs, of use lxc-attach, which is the easiest option:

```
you@hostbox:/$ lxc-attach -n yourlxc
root@yourlxc:/# adduser username
```

Comment: FWIW, I had to install the `lxc-utils` package to get `lxc-attach` on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

The q. is pretty old, the other answers are too and it is yet again different. What we do use to access shell in a linux container is ***exec*** command - similar to what we have in kubes:

```
lxc exec <cont name> -- <cmd line>
```

if that is ubuntu then cmd line may be "bash" and it gives you a shell in a container as root.